# NSLayoutConstraints error

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, programmatically-created

I like to layout constraints in code.. but for some reason my latest swift project is throwing errors my way.. my constraint code is this.

```
    let views = ["optionsView":optionsView, "cameraView":cameraView, "imageView":imageView]
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-[optionsView(300)]-[cameraView(300)]-[imageView(300)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: views))
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[optionsView(500)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: views))
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[cameraView(500)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: views))
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[imageView(500)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: views))
```

For all four constraints, Xcode throws an error, telling me that the last function parameter - views - is invalid. The error message is thus:

```
'String' is not identical to 'NSObject'
```

any ideas?? plz and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `NSLayoutFormatOptions(0)`. Just say `nil`.

Oh, also, all your views are Optionals. You need to unwrap all of them!

```
let views = ["optionsView":optionsView!, "cameraView":cameraView!, "imageView":imageView!]
```

Comment: right on!  but.. no cigar, this isn't the solution I'm looking for.  Do you think this is an Xcode 6 problem?? I use this function all the time and I'm using basic UIViews..

Comment: Okay, got it. It's the Optionals.

Comment: optionals? you mean I can't use optional variables?

Comment: Do you know Swift? Do you understand what an Optional is?

Comment: yes, Im giving the dictionary weak references that are optionals  - that I set in viewDidLoad. I cannot use optionals?

Comment: Did you even look at the code I've given you? I've shown you what to do.

Comment: This is a good use case for you to write a bug report to Apple. The Swift compiler error message here was totally off the mark!

Comment: However, I should add, it would also be good for you to learn Swift before using it any further; an Optional containing a UIView is not a UIView, and that fact that you don't know that, and that you don't understand the notion of unwrapping, is a very serious conceptual hole.